# How can you rebuild credit in Hong Kong?

Tags: hong-kong

I do not know if secured credit cards do not exist in Hong Kong.

Then how else can credit be rebuilt? My in-laws had credit card debt 20 years ago that is still on the credit report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TransUnion, the only credit information provider in Hong Kong, keeps [negative information on your credit report tends to fall off five years after the accounts are settled, or eight if you’ve been through bankruptcy](http://www.transunion.hk/education/credit-report-is-important). If a 20-year-old credit card debt has been settled but still be found on the report, you might need to contact TransUnion and see if a correction shall be made.

One way to rebuilt the credit score is to get a credit card if you do not, use it, and make sure the payments are on-time. Secured credit cards does not exist in Hong Kong but chances of getting credit cards are high if you have a stable income or have been maintaining a high balance in the bank.